# Rebuild features on cache clear

Tags: caching, features, distributions

I have a distro with many preinstalled features (Panopoly).

Since I have upgraded core to 7.24 I can see an additional setting at admin/structure/features/settings, see attachment.

[image]

On production, is it best to disable the "Rebuild features on cache clear"? This is active by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is best to disable this in production for the performance reasons mentioned.

I think the only times you would want to rebuild the feature list is when you are using the features and/or modules lists (as designed). Spending the resources to reload that when clearing cache for themeing purposes would be unnecessary.

Comment: great! thanks. i will post this on the project's issue log or they need that to be a hidden 6 levels deep option? maybe it should be written in the README.txt... (i need to start reading that stuff :)